# Geocoding returns two possible locations but presents wrong address as most accurate and right address is least accurate

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

using https://www.google.ca/maps and the geocoding api gives the same results:

using https://www.google.ca/maps and searching for:
 143 GARRISON CIR , RED DEER, AB , Canada

returns two results:

143 Garrison PL
143 Garrison Cir

using the API reveals that it considers the first one '... Pl' more accurate than '... Cir' when clearly the second one is more true to the original addressed used to search since it contains 'Cir'...

using:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=143%20GARRISON%20CIR%20%2C%20RED%20DEER%2C%20AB%20%2C%20Canada

reveals the first result's accuracy is:
ROOFTOP

and the second result's accuracy is:
RANGE_INTERPOLATED  {not as accurate}

WHY???

Interestingly... if I use the postal code in the full address {which I verified with Canada Post as being correct}:

'143 GARRISON CIR , RED DEER, AB T4P0P5, Canada'

I get no results from either method!

again... WHY???

Answer (score 0):

The RANGE_INTERPOLATED result means that there is no exact street address feature in the Google database and the service tries to guess where the address is located. Maybe due to this reason the exact ROOFTOP result is scored higher than an interpolation. Especially taking into account that the coordinates of both results are very close to each other:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D143%2520GARRISON%2520CIR%2520%252C%2520RED%2520DEER%252C%2520AB%2520%252C%2520Canada

In order to solve this you should report a missing address to Google using Send feedback mechanism:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045

Also note that an interpolated result for the address has a different postal code T4N 3M4. Even more, if I try to search the postal code T4P 0P5, I'll get back only postal code prefix T4P:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DCA%26in_postal_code%3DT4P%25200P5

That means the postal code T4P 0P5 is also missing from Google database and you should report it as well.

As the postal code is missing you are getting ZERO_RESULTS for complete string `143 GARRISON CIR , RED DEER, AB T4P0P5, Canada`

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D143%2520GARRISON%2520CIR%2520%252C%2520RED%2520DEER%252C%2520AB%2520T4P0P5%252C%2520Canada%26options%3Dtrue

As you mentioned, we can see that the same behavior is reproducible on maps.google.com. There are two options for the address and Garrison Pl is the first item while Garrison Cir is the second. That confirms that this is a data issue rather than API issue:

[image]

I hope this explains your doubt.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time... I did report it to https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045

no results yet.

Also, regarding your statement:

Comment: Thanks , I did report it.

Also, regarding your statement:
"That confirms that this is a data issue rather than API issue:"

I agree that it is a data issue since both the 'pl' and 'cir' responses return the wrong postal code (according to Canada Post) but I think it's also an API issue since the original address I typed, clearly matches the second response better regardless of the fact that one is 'RANGE_INTERPOLATED' and the other is 'ROOFTOP' ... I guess this result takes precedence over how well the original typed address matches the returned formatted address...